# How does 'Number' in Array.prototype.filter(Number) work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found this cool way of using the `Array.prototype.filter` method to remove all non-numbers from a string, but am not entirely sure how it's using the `Number` prototype to achieve this:

```
var arr = '75number9';

arr.split(/[^\d]/).filter(Number); // returns [75, 9]
```

When I check `typeof Number` I get back `'function'`.  What is going on here?

Adding further to my confusion is that if I replace `Number` with `String`, the results are the same.  It still works!

```
arr.split(/[^\d]/).filter(String); // returns [75, 9]
```

`Array` and `Object` as parameters, on the other hand, return this:

```
["75", "", "", "", "", "", "9"]
```

Very curious to understand this!

Comment: some types can be functions. [`Function object (implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 terms) "function"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @13ruce1337: All "types" are functions, since in javascript a class and a constructor are one and the same

Comment: @Eric I was just breaking my brain a few seconds ago thinking that...thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: All primitive type constructors return the type coerced value of the first argument if you don't use `new` when invoking it. An empty string's numeric conversion is to `0`, which is falsey, so it's removed. Any non-convertible values will be converted to `NaN`, which is also falsey.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but if you make the regexp "greedy" you won't need to filter the result: `split(/[^\d]+/)`

Comment: @Strille Yes indeed :) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @13ruce1337— "Type" is defined in [*EMCA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8). All values have a Type. Functions always return a value (even if it's *undefined*), and that value has a Type. Functions like String, Boolean, Number, etc. return a primitive value of their associated type when called as a function with a single argument, e.g. `Number(foo)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Number` is a (constructor) function trying to return a number. Give it a literal number or *a string which can be parsed to a number*, and it returns that number. Give it something else, and it returns `NaN`.

Filter returns the values for which the callback function (in this case `Number`) returns a truthy value. Numbers which are `!= 0` and `!= NaN` are truthy, and are thus returned.

As so, your example does not return `0` values:

```
var arr = '75number0';
arr.split(/[^\d]/).filter(Number);
// ["75"]
```

Notice that the values of the returned array are still strings. If we want them to be numbers, we can use `map()`:

```
arr.split(/[^\d]/).filter(Number).map(Number);
// [75, 9]
```

In the case of using the `String` constructor instead of `Number`, it works because `String` is returning empty strings for the empty strings it is given, and empty strings (`''`) are falsy just like `0`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the gotcha that this breaks expectations for `"0"`.

Comment: Good catch!  The question then goes on to ask for a sum of the resultant numbers, so in this case the 0 would have been unnecessary, but point well taken :)

Comment: "Numbers which are `!= 0` are truthy" yes, might note that it also must be not NaN, seeing as NaN is of type Number (`typeof NaN === 'number'`).

Comment: *"Give it something else, and it returns NaN"* Not 100% correct: `Number(true)` returns `1`. `Number` simply converts the input to a number according to the spec. Some values will be converted to `NaN`, which is falsy.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Fabrício. It was also pretty important for the topic.

Comment: @Mikke—there is always ECMA-262. When Number is called as a function with a single value, it performs type conversion as defined in [*ToNumber*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3). If *value* is an expression, it is first evaluated and the resulting value passed to *ToNumber*, where even Objects can return a number or NaN.

Answer (score 1):

```
> var arr = '75number9';
> arr = arr.split(/[^\d]/)
> arr
["75", "", "", "", "", "", "9"]
```

`Number` is the constructor for the boxed `Number` type. For some reason, it is also usable as a function:

```
> Number("")
0
> Number("75")
75
```

`filter` keeps elements where the invocation results in a non-falsey value. When the empty string is passed, it returns 0, which is falsey, so the empty strings are discarded

`String`, when given a string argument, does nothing but return it. Since `""` is falsey, `filter` rejects empty strings again.

Comment: Constructors _are_ functions. See the spec for the `Number` function.

Comment: @SLaks: Indeed, but it's unusual for a constructor to have a return value

Comment: "For some reason, it is also usable as a function" The reason is the specification. See [15.7.1 The Number Constructor Called as a Function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1), more specifically [15.7.1.1 Number ( \[ value \] )](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1.1).

Comment: @Eric—all of the constructors that correlate to Types return a value of that type (String, Number, Boolean, Object) when called as a function. It's not that common to use them that way because coercion does the job, e.g. `+foo` rather than `Number(foo)`, though the latter is often used for clarity.

Comment: @RobG: Careful with your capitalization: `Number(1) instanceof Number` is false (but `typeof Number(1) == 'number'`)

Comment: @Eric—not sure what your point is. All the built–in constructors and objects have names starting with a capital letter. ECMA-262 capitalises the names of [Types](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8), though the string returned by *typeof* is lower case, I guess you need to ask Brendan Eich about that. Primitives fail an *instanceof* test because they don't have a `[[Prototype]]` property. *instanceof* and *typeof* are entirely different tests.